# updating and displaying ratings from a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database

For practice, I'm creating a website that shows the ratings of professors. I'm confused about how to approach this though. Since the rating can change and is made up of reviews from students, where do I put this information? Does my professor have a "rating" column in his table? Or do I have a table for reviews, and when I display rating on the professor's page, it has to calculate the rating from all the reviews first?

For context, this will be done using MySQL and phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't need to persist the Rating on the professor table in the database unless it was for Data Warehousing purposes.

The Rating could be calculated in your Model from related reviews to display in the UI.

Comment: so I'll have a "name" column in my professor table. That will link to multiple ratings in my ratings table? Then when I display it on my page, I'm actually asking MySQL to pull all the ratings linked to that professor's name, calculate the average, and display it?

Comment: I wouldnt link the table by Name.   Professor Table would be

Comment: Professor -  ID  - Identifier column (generated) Primary key

Comment: Sorry, keep hitting enter to go to new line =)     Have a unique Idenitifer in the Professor Table like ID.     In  your Review Table have a ProfessorId column that is a foreign Key back to Id in Professor Table.   Names can change and throw off your linkage

Answer (score 1):

Make one table for professors and another separate table for ratings, link the two using foreign key.

Comment: so I'll have a "name" column in my professor table. That will link to multiple ratings in my ratings table? Then when I display it on my page, I'm actually asking MySQL to pull all the ratings linked to that professor's name, calculate the average, and display it?